# Linear Regression to create a predictive model to calculate wine quality

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a machine learning model to predict wine quality by alcohol level and acidity.
Im new to machine learning and after thorough searching, 
I still  can't decide whether linear regression or neural networks will best solve the problem?
I'm using matlab 2013a and I would really appreciate if someone can help me decide which one to use? Which one will be easier to implement and which will yield better performance?

Comment: Linear regression is simple to implement and should work just fine to fit some data with 2 independent variables. This isn't really a programming problem, more a maths/stats problem.

Comment: In my experience the best performances are achieved using Merlot.

Comment: Linear regression can only fit linear patterns, which is not clear that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to decide which model fits better your data, you need to do cross-validation with an additional data set, namely *training*, *test* and *validation*. The last set is used to select the model or model parameters that provide better generalisation.